# Error: No viable overloaded =

Tags: c++

I have a class which looks like this:

```
class MemberListEntry {
public:
    int id;
    short port;
    long heartbeat;
    long timestamp;
    MemberListEntry(int id, short port, long heartbeat, long timestamp);
    MemberListEntry(int id, short port);
    MemberListEntry(): id(0), port(0), heartbeat(0), timestamp(0) {}
    MemberListEntry(const MemberListEntry &anotherMLE);
    MemberListEntry& operator =(const MemberListEntry &anotherMLE);
    int getid();
    short getport();
    long getheartbeat();
    long gettimestamp();
    void setid(int id);
    void setport(short port);
    void setheartbeat(long hearbeat);
    void settimestamp(long timestamp);
};
```

The I have some code which instantiates it like this:

```
   int id = stoi(address.substr(0, pos));
   short port = (short)stoi(address.substr(pos + 1, address.size()-pos-1));
   memcpy(&addr[0], &id, sizeof(int));
   memcpy(&addr[4], &port, sizeof(short));

  MemberListEntry mEntry;
  mEntry = new MemberListEntry(id, port);
```

I am getting this error:

```
 error: no viable overloaded '='
 mEntry = new MemberListEntry(id, port);
```

Any idea what could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: `new MemberListEntry` returns a `MemberListEntry*`; `mEntry` is an ordinary `MemberListEntry`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code should be

```
MemberListEntry * mEntry;
mEntry = new MemberListEntry(id, port);
```

You are allocating an object on heap using new operator which returns pointer to the object created and you are trying to assign a pointer to an object.

Better alternative here would be allocate object on stack which you are doing it already.

`MemberListEntry mEntry(id, port);`

This creates and initializes the object and it will be destructed automatically when your function goes out of scope.

Fun fact: This not java, it's C++. :)

Hope this helps.